# how to track activation link click from correct email address

Tags: email, laravel

I am creating user registration page with email activation link in Laravel 5.1.
I send activation link to entered correct email address. How to find activation
link is click from correct email address where I send mail

Comment: If What you are asking is how to ensure the activation link is clicked from the intended email account and not from another email address then you dont know how this works. If you send email to me as long as you did copy another person only me will receive the email and only me know the content. Seems you don't understand how email works

Comment: @ mr.digitlimit I know how email works .

Answer (score 0):

To give you an idea how this could work:

1. When user registers generate a per user unique token for the new user (e.g. 60be22f4-e849-4676-b64b-c3493e8709e0)
2. Save this unique token in your database along with the user name and password
3. Send this unique token along with your activation email (e.g. as a link: `http://my-domain.com/user/confirm/60be22f4-e849-4676-b64b-c3493e8709e0`)
4. When a user clicks this link search for the unique id in your user table and mark this user as active/confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty simple way of doing this:

1. Store a 'secret' for each user in your database, this should be generated on the first creation and shouldn't change for the life of the user in the system. Secret could be a simple string like 'ajchdu8'
2. Set up an activation route that contains the user ID and their 'activation signature' like so http://yourdomain.com/activate/{user_id}/{signature}
3. Create a mechanism for generating and comparing those signatures and use the secret for each user as a way of making user only that user can activate their account (or who ever you give the URL to anyways)

The signature is basically just a hash of things that we know about the user but doesn't change in the database so it could just be a hash of user id and their secret then by providing the user id in the link you can look up in the database the user by the id to get their secret and any other details you require to verify the signature.

Comment: I already did this method in laravel 5. i need to prevent user who give email address and they click from that mail id alone.

Comment: @user1959811 What are you talking about? If you send an email to a user, this email is unique to that user and if user receive the mail he simply click on the to confirm the email address belongs to him

Comment: in case , that user forward mail to someother mail address and click from that mail address also.how we prevent that event? For example, i send activation link to address A but user forward my link to address B and click from address B.we must prevent that scenario and check user must click from address A alone not from address B

Comment: @user1959811 you're literally asking for the impossible if a user shares an email meant for them then that link will work regardless. You shouldn't try to fight this or you'll annoy users, a lot of people have multiple email accounts and forward their email between accounts which even if this mechanism could exist for checking the source of email links it would stop users with alias email accounts